# How were printouts done on Commodore PETs

Tags: commodore-pet, printer

In the old PC mags, there were often printouts of code from Commodore PETs.  How were these done?  Even though the PET had a GPIB interface, it didn't have a print command.

The method that we used in 1978 was a little machine code program to show one line at a time on the top of the screen and then screen scrape it and send each character to the GPIB.  This worked but was quite slow.

Was there a better technique for achieving printouts?

Comment: For me, with pen and paper.

Comment: In June 1978, the TX-80 (TP-80), an eighty-column dot matrix printer, was released to the market and was mainly used as a system printer for the Commodore PET computer. Personally My own printer a few years later was the MX-80 and I could use that with my tethered Hand Held Brick (Psion Organiser) or use that to Drive HP Plotters or plot to a flatbed plotter or another brick with a motorised arm and a pen in its hand as faster than using stencils on AO drawings. but before that we used punch cards and punched tape for printing.

Comment: We used a Dolphin BD80.  Problem was the paper.  Sometimes it was letter, sometimes it was A4.  Working out how many linefeeds for invoices was  a bit tedious depending on paper type.  Sometimes the printouts italicised themselves.  Never found out the reason for that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I used to:

```
OPEN 4,4:
CMD 4:
LIST
```

`CMD` redirected the `$FFD2` output routine to the specified file.

Of course, you needed a printer that understood the PET special characters. The CBM 2022 and 2023 did.

Comment: There were as well GPIB->Centronics or Serial interfaces. Also, people were taking literal pictures. Much the same way as magazines took screen-shots with more professional setup available using film or Polaroid.

Comment: I didn't know about this one.  Looks really simple compared to what we used to do.

Comment: @cup See page 78/79 of the [PET User Manual](http://www.zimmers.net/anonftp/pub/cbm/manuals/pet/Pet_User_Manual_Model_2001-8.pdf) or p.80/81 of the original PET Users Handbook](http://www.zimmers.net/anonftp/pub/cbm/manuals/pet/PET%20Users%20Handbook.pdf).

Comment: I don't think the Commodore 2001s we had had any manuals.  The handbook looks familiar but that came out a lot later.  I just worked out what to do by experimentation and looking at the supplied programs and magazine articles.  Typing out stuff on the calculator style keyboard was really painful.